# Summing a particular product of binomial coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I expect this is elementary, but I can't find a closed form. Let $a_i$, $i=1,...,m$, be a sequence of natural numbers and $n>\sum a_i$. What is the value of the sum:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{n}{k-j}(-1)^{j}\binom{j+1}{a_1}\cdots\binom{j+1}{a_m}?$$

Obviously it is zero if $k\geq n$. Otherwise one expects a closed form.

Comment: Why would you expect that this is elementary? What setting does this occur in that suggests it has a closed form?

Comment: If $m=1$ it reduces to Chu-Vandermonde. Otherwise it is the Cauchy sum of the pointwise product of such polynomials, at integer values. I expect this is quite well known to those working in Algebra and Combinatorics. Unfortunately I don't!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see Vandermonde's identity in this. Can you demonstrate how? $a_1$ is fixed right?